# ScrollIntoView for dynamic lists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, js-scrollintoview

[Here is code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-snowflake-cdjgfy?file=/src/App.js)

I need to scroll the element to the top of the page. But the problem is that list (which contains the element) is asynchronous. And I can not predict the height of elements on top and after the element.
I was trying different approaches. And because of the fact that I can not put any code into the elements (to check if they are finishing their load process), I decided to stop on setTimeout. But it's not a good solution.
Is it possible to avoid it?
I'm using react for that. But it could be a general JS question.

Comment: Hello! Codesandbox link is empty.

Comment: Oh my apologies. I have added updated link.